# how to get the selected list attribute value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a created a list of options and i have could multiselect the list. all i want to know is how could i know which are the items from the list is selected. on click i m adding an attribute to the list.as below.

Comment: __Side Note__: use `$(this).data("role-selected","selected")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an attribute, use it along with [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
var $selected = $('#user-role > li[data-role-selected="selected"]')
```